# Please help me understand this concatenated SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm expanding my understanding of SQL injection (i'm a pentester). In this case, i'm playing with mysql.

I came across an exercise where injecting this payload was part of the answer:
`' || (select '' from users where username='administrator') || --'`

I don't understand how the concat works in this case. So i headed over to https://extendsclass.com/mysql-online.html to play around.

Using this simple example of what a similar query would look like one it reaches the sql server. This code works, it returns one row with the string 'albert'.

`select firstname from scientist where firstname = 'albert' || (select '' )  ;`

Could someone please help me understand why the || works and where and when the (select '') gets evaluated? I guess the thing i don't understand is how we can concat a new select statement with a string 'albert' and still make a valid query. However, i think i'm misunderstanding what is happening.

Thanks.

EDIT:
This returns 4 rows of 1. All good. just what i expect.
select 1 from information_schema.columns where table_name = concat('scien','tist');

This does not return anything:
select 2 from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'scien'||'tist';

This returns all columns for all tables:
select * from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'scienist' || True;

Am i crazy, or does || mean OR rather than concat?

Comment: In MySql [||](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/logical-operators.html#operator_or) serves as OR.

Answer (score 0):

Any query that returns a singleton (one tuple, one column) can be considered an atomic value.

in the cases you list, all queries return a single string.

Thus, you are concatenating this string to the other strings:

'this is an ' || (select 'example' )

is equivalent to

execute select 'example', which returns one tuple/one column: example

thus:

'this is an ' || 'example'

resulting in

'this is an example'

Comment: thanks. i'm not sure that explains it tho. This query will return all column names from all tables: select * from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'scientist' || (True);  -I don't think True is concatenated with 'scientist' e.g. scientestTrue, it seems to act more like an or statement, e.g.  ...where table_name = 'scientest' or True; returns the same as the above query.

Comment: I think you are using two different "versions" of: ||
if the arguments are boolean, || does "or" ( as in "table name = 'scientist' || true) 
if the arguments are string, it does concatenation (as in "'albert' || (select ''). In your original question you are using the string version.